# Null Coordinates gauge in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

I have read several explanations about Penrose diagrams, null coordinates, null hypersurfaces. I wish to verify my understanding (after searching through literature, google and this forum and not finding a clear confirmation):

Coordinates gauge freedom in General Relativity allows me to choose a set of coordinates ($x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3$) such that $x^0$ and $x^1$ are null coordinates. This means that I put the following constraints on the metric tensor components for all events throughout spacetime

$g_{00}=g_{11}=0$

$g_{01}=g_{10}=1$ (different conventions can have this be -1)

Other components of $g_{\mu \nu}$ are unconstrained

In the language of hypersurfaces and tangent vectors, if at some event P in spacetime the direction $\partial/\partial{x^0}$ is the normal vector of some null hypersurface going through P, then $\partial/\partial{x^1}$ is the null-transverse vector to $\partial/\partial{x^0}$.

My questions here are:

1. As long as the $g_{\mu \nu}$ in this frame-of-reference has 1 negative eigenvalue and 3 positive eigenvalues (for all events in spacetime), the metric is valid, correct?
2. Fixing coordinates (among the coordinates gauge freedom) usually means there are 4 mathematical constraints I can impose on the metric without over-restricting it. It looks like null-coordinates gauge above includes only 3 constraints and so I still have some freedom in choosing coordinates left, correct?